# JOLT Spec with merging Nested arrays from multiple levels and read parent key value under child

Tags: jolt

I'm struggling to get the desired out put. can someone help me to find the right solution.

I tried with different specifications and noting worked. I'm facing issues when adding the parent id under respective array.

Please help here.

**Input JSON:**

```
{
  "device": {
    "id": "336 A6",
    "shelves": [
      {
        "shelfID": "1",
        "slots": [
          {
            "slotID": "1",
            "cards": {
              "cardID": "1",
              "subSlots": [
                {
                  "slotID": "mda-1",
                  "cards": {
                    "cardID": "1/1",
                    "ports": [
                      {
                        "portID": "1/1/1",
                        "adminStatus": "up"
                      },
                      {
                        "portID": "1/1/2",
                        "adminStatus": "up"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "slotID": "mda-2",
                  "cards": {
                    "cardID": "2/1",
                    "ports": [
                      {
                        "portID": "2/1/1",
                        "adminStatus": "up"
                      },
                      {
                        "portID": "2/1/2",
                        "adminStatus": "up"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "slotID": "11",
            "cards": {
              "cardID": "11",
              "ports": [
                {
                  "portID": "11/1/1",
                  "adminStatus": "up"
                },
                {
                  "portID": "11/1/2",
                  "adminStatus": "up"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "shelfID": "esat-1",
        "ports": [
          {
            "portID": "esat-1/1/1",
            "adminStatus": "down"
          },
          {
            "portID": "esat-1/1/2",
            "adminStatus": "up"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Below is the JOLT spec I tried

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "device": {
        "shelves": {
          "*": {
            "ports": {
              "*": "physicalResource.ports[&2]",
              "@(1,shelfID)": "physicalResource.ports[&2].parentId"
            },
            "slots": {
              "*": {
                "cards": {
                  "ports": {
                    "*": "physicalResource.ports[&5]",
                    "@(1,cardID)": "physicalResource.ports[&5].parentId"
                  },
                  "subSlots": {
                    "*": {
                      "cards": {
                        "ports": {
                          "*": "physicalResource.ports[&8]",
                          "@(1,cardID)": "physicalResource.ports[&8].parentId"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

### Expected Output:

```
{
  "physicalResource": {
    "ports": [
      {
        "id": "1/1/1",
        "parentId": "1/1",
        "state": "up"
      },
      {
        "id": "1/1/2",
        "parentId": "1/1",
        "state": "up"
      },
      {
        "id": "2/1/1",
        "parentId": "2/1",
        "state": "up"
      },
      {
        "id": "2/1/2",
        "parentId": "2/1",
        "state": "up"
      },
      {
        "id": "11/1/1",
        "parentId": "11/1",
        "state": "up"
      },
      {
        "id": "11/1/2",
        "parentId": "11/1",
        "state": "up"
      },
      {
        "id": "11/1/1",
        "parentId": "11/1",
        "state": "up"
      },
      {
        "id": "11/1/2",
        "parentId": "11/1",
        "state": "up"
      },
      {
        "id": "esat-1/1/1",
        "parentSubCardId": "esat-1",
        "state": "up"
      },
      {
        "id": "esat-1/1/2",
        "parentSubCardId": "esat-1",
        "state": "up"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can some one help me on this please?

Comment: You can submit a new issue on their GitHub: https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in two shifts

1. First shift creates groups using array indexes and types.
2. Second shift coverts those groups into an array

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "device": {
        "shelves": {
          "*": {
            "ports": {
              "*": {
                "@(2,shelfID)": "ports_&3_&1.parentSubCardId",
                "portID": "ports_&3_&1.id",
                "adminStatus": "ports_&3_&1.state"
              }
            },
            "slots": {
              "*": {
                "cards": {
                  "ports": {
                    "*": {
                      "@(2,cardID)": "slots_cards_&4_&1.parentId",
                      "portID": "slots_cards_&4_&1.id",
                      "adminStatus": "slots_cards_&4_&1.state"
                    }
                  },
                  "subSlots": {
                    "*": {
                      "cards": {
                        "ports": {
                          "*": {
                            "@(2,cardID)": "sub_slots_&4_&1.parentId",
                            "portID": "sub_slots_&4_&1.id",
                            "adminStatus": "sub_slots_&4_&1.state"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "physicalResource.ports[]"
    }
  }
]
```

I'd suggest running it without the second shift to see whats going on.